# Assign or replace uiview to another uivew

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

How can i assign or replace a UIView To another UIView.I am not able to assign a view to the another view..Anybody have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Could you explain what it is you are trying to do? In terms of what you want it to look like before and after? It's not very clear from your question

Comment: There are two views, UIView *view1 in which i have drawn a circle ,and UIView *view2 which i have drawn a square .Now after assigning view2=view1 view2 should give me a circle, how can i do that.Even after calling [view2 setNeedsDisplay] nothing happens.view2 still displays a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say your main view is `self.view`. You want to add a new view to this view dynamically. You do the following -

`[self.view addSubview:someNewView]`

To place it in certain location use `CGRectMake` on `somenewView` to place it exactly where you want to in the parent view `self.view`.

to remove `someNewView` from `self.view` simply do - `[someNewView removeFromSuperView];`